# Which answer should you accept when both answers are correct but use different techniques?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

There can be many ways to solve a single problem, and many Ask Ubuntu questions accordingly receive multiple answers using different methods

In this case, which answer should I accept?

Comment: If both are correct, just choose which you like more ;-)

Comment: And don't pay attention to which one's first.  Our goal is to fuel building a Q&A resource, not a how-fast-can-you-spew-an-answer contest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If both answers are correct, you might also consider how the respondent approached the problem, how efficient the solution is, and how they presented it. Of course, this might be overthinking, but if both answers satisfy the criteria you might exted the criteria. Among other things, leave a comment telling why you chose a particular answer. Personally , I'm here to learn and improve my skill set, hence I find it beneficial in receiving feedback.

**TL;DR**: if both cakes are good, consider each server's customer service

Answer (score 12):

The one you prefer, the one you end up using. It's completely up to you.

Acceptance is very personal, it's your question. Accept whichever answer you want.

Comment: Just don't accept anything blatantly wrong ;)