# Which answer to accept if all are equally correct and important

Tags: discussion

I am facing a dilemma here. I have asked this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/694315/294611) answers to which are all good and equally correct. All give something good to learn

In such situation accepting one will make other *less correct*  since **accepting** implies the most correct answer. Now what to do?

Comment: Also [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14070/295286)